# how to create database in sqlite3 in react native

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-ios, cordova-sqlite-storage

I went through all the details here in this link https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage. And I got confused with their documentation.

```
 ...
  1.SQLite.openDatabase({name : "testDB", createFromLocation : 1}, okCallback,errorCallback);
  // default - if your folder is called www and data file is named the same as the dbName - testDB in this example
  2.SQLite.openDatabase({name : "testDB", createFromLocation : "~data/mydbfile.sqlite"}, okCallback,errorCallback);
  // if your folder is called data rather than www or your filename does not match the name of the db
  3.SQLite.openDatabase({name : "testDB", createFromLocation : "/data/mydbfile.sqlite"}, okCallback,errorCallback);
  // if your folder is not in app bundle but in app sandbox i.e. downloaded from some remote location.
  ...
```

what the above statements will do ?
will it create a database or will it open a database which is there inside `www` or `asset` folder ?
can I create the database in whichever folder I want ?

No where i found a clear answer on this. That's why i'm asking this in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem sometimes ago. You need to do all the setup according to the documentation. After that if you provide the location of the `database.db` using `createFromLocation` then you have to create a empty database file and paste it manually in assets and if you don't want to create manually then you can simply use `SQLite.openDatabase({name : "testDB"})` it will create itself a database as the name provided. Hope this will help you, please tell me if it works.

Comment: I have `{name : "testDB", createFromLocation : 1}` initially, and it was success. Then i changed the name of file in assets to `testDB1` & then  `{name : "testDB1", createFromLocation : 1}`. I cleared the app data and rerun the project. Then it throwed `error cannot open database`. What was internally happening there is so confusing.

Comment: I just need to know. Whether i can create database on specific folder or not. And also to populate data why we need different steps for ios and android. I came from nativescript background and there it's damn easy for both the platform as it uses same code.

Comment: @rock if you use prepopulated db then you have to specify the location of the db also use the specific folder and if you don't have the prepopulated db then it doesn't need to provide the location.  For prepopulated try this [example] (https://aboutreact.com/example-of-pre-populated-sqlite-database-in-react-native/)  and for simple try this [example] (https://aboutreact.com/example-of-sqlite-database-in-react-native/)

Comment: @rock re run the project after linking command i.e. `react-native link` in case of changing the attributes of any component

Comment: I'm using android and location doesn't considered as per documentation

Comment: @rock `createFromLocation : 1` it means the root folder `www`. if you specify it means you are using prepopulated database